# Wicket calling a lengthy operation and updating through ajax

Tags: java, web-applications, web, osgi, wicket

Based on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856698/wicket-concurrent-ajax-requests-limited-to-one), I've come to an understanding that Wicket queues subsequent AJAX requests. Now my page is ridden with several AJAX requests and I'd like to add one more that spawns a lengthy operation.

```
public void populateItem(final Item item) {
  final MyObject object = (MyObject) item.getModelObject();
  // ... a couple of fields
  Label statusLabel = new Label("status", new AbstractReadOnlyModel() {
    @Override
    public Object getObject() {
      return someService.doSomeLengthyOperation();
    }
  });
  statusLabel.add(new AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(5)));
  item.add(statusLabel)
}
```

Once this Ajax request fires, it could take up to one minute for it to finish executing. The problem here is that `someService.doSomeLengthyOperation()` will be executed `n times the number of rows` that I have, meaning I'll be queueing up `n times two-minutes`. Now, as I've mentioned, Wicket queues subsequent AJAX requests.

What happens is it takes me `number-of-rows * minutes-it-take-to-finish-the-operation` to load the page or do other stuff that requires AJAX like

```
new AjaxButton("ajax-button"){
  @Override
  protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form form) {
    //.. this won't be executed until all the statusLabels have finished invoking getObject()
  }
}
```

I'd like to avoid creating a web service exposing my service and having to write my own AJAX calls. What are my options? (Using Wicket 1.5 / Pax-Wicket)

Comment: Can you more detailed explain your problem? You have a ListView with items where the lenghtyOperation causes the ListView items very slowly appear. And then again when the ListView finished you got a full queue of ajax requests? What is the desired behavior you expect?

Comment: Ah bugger, did I explain it better this time? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Take a look at http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxChannel.html I still dont understand fully. The problem is that populating the listview many ajaxrequest block you in fact the possibility to submit using the button because th request will be the last in the queue?

Comment: Yeah, more or less. Considering that the operation I do inside the `getObject()` method could take up to several minutes, it will block other AJAX requests (e.g. the `AjaxButton#onSubmit`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to have the initial Ajax request return fast (without any results) and add an [AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.5.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior.html) to the target component. This Behavior would then check an intervals (like every 10 seconds or so) if there's a result. If there's a result it should update the component ans remove itself.

This way you can do the operation in a separate task without blocking your Ajax calls.

To elaborate a bit, I created a runnable [quickstart](http://wicket-game.gwassist.de/uploads/LongNonBlockingAjaxCallsDemo.zip) that issues 5 Ajax calls like you have described, each running a random amount of time between 10 seconds and one minute. At the same time, there is a responsive AjaxLink with a counter.

The main idea is to separate the actual Ajax calls from the calls to the slow method.

```
add(new ListView<DataHolder>("list", list) {

    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem<DataHolder> item) {
        DataHolder dh = item.getModelObject();
        item.add(new Label("itemNumber", new PropertyModel<Integer>(dh, "number")));
        Label result = new Label("itemResult", new PropertyModel<String>(dh, "result"));
        result.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        result.add(new AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(2)));
        item.add(result);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Processor(item.getModelObject()));
        thread.start();
    }
});
```

As you can see, the label model doesn't directly call `doSomeLengthyOperation()` anymore. Instead a new Thread is spawned that does the heavy lifting. The Processor class just implements the Runnable interface and uses the run-method to do the work (in your case, in the demo it just waits some time).

The getter for the PropertyModel encapsulates this stunt and makes it transparent while allways returning fast to prevent blocking.

```
public String getResult() {
    String retValue;
    if (!processed) {
        retValue = String.format("Still busy after %d requests", counter++);
    } else {
        retValue = result;
    }
    return retValue;
}
```

The processed member is just a flag, that the Processor uses to indicate whe it's done waiting (ehr working).

Since you'll probably issuing more than 5 Threads at the same time, I'd recommend to use some sort of Threadpool but that's beyond the scope of this little demo.

---

Disclaimer: This is no production code. It's just for demoing. It will not be nice to your resources nor will it handle any lack thereof gracefully. It will not work when the user hit's reload or anything else happens.

Comment: Thanks mate, but I'm actually polling for some sort of status, so removing the the `AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior` is a no go :(

Comment: Then don't remove it. That's in no way needed for this solution.

Comment: My problem is it will clog the queue if I don't remove it, and if I do, I won't be able to update it more than once. Actually looking for a solution that allows me to run my Ajax calls asynchronously.

Comment: I don't think, you're understanding my idea. I'll edit my answer shortly to include some demo code .

Comment: actually, how I solved it was expose a web service for the method and write my own `Ajax` calls, but your answer is definitely the Wicket way of solving it. Thanks for clarifying and sorry for the very late reply.

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure if WicketStuff Async Task could help you but give it a try:

https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/wiki/Async-tasks

Here is the short demo that is in the Async Tasks project:

```
public class DemoPage extends WebPage implements IRunnableFactory {

public DemoPage() {

    Form<?> form = new Form<Void>("form");
    AbstractTaskContainer taskContainer = DefaultTaskManager.getInstance()
        .makeContainer(1000L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    ProgressButton progressButton = new ProgressButton("button", form, 
        Model.of(taskContainer), this, Duration.milliseconds(500L));
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar("bar", progressButton);

    add(form);
    form.add(progressButton);
    form.add(progressBar);
}

@Override
public Runnable getRunnable() {
    return new IProgressObservableRunnable() {
        // Runnable implementation.
    };
}
```