# Preloader in Wicket Application

Tags: wicket, ajax-request

In a wicket application on search event it takes few secons and sometimes minutes to show the result as its a long data . I want to show a preloader while the data is fetched from the database to let the user know something is going on when they click search . I am very new to wicket application , dont understands the things very deeply but I find AjaxLazyPreloader but as I said I want to show the preloader when the search method is called ...I am sharing the SearchSubmit method ...

```
private void processSearchSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget ajaxRequestTarget) {

        ajaxRequestTarget.add(tableHolder);
        ajaxRequestTarget.add(productTableHolder);
        if (zipcode == null) {
            ajaxRequestTarget
                    .appendJavaScript("$().toastmessage('showWarningToast','Please enter a zipcode')");
        } else if (!ZipCodeValidator.isValid(zipcode)) {
            useZones = true;
            currentZone = zipcode;
            ajaxRequestTarget.add(tableHolder);
            if (searchProduct != null) {
                ajaxRequestTarget.add(productTableHolder);
                if (lstProduct.getList().size() == 0) {
                    ajaxRequestTarget
                            .appendJavaScript("$().toastmessage('showErrorToast','Sorry! This product is not avialable .')");
                }
            }


        } else if (lstMerchants.getList().size() == 0) {
            ajaxRequestTarget
                    .appendJavaScript("$().toastmessage('showWarningToast','Sorry! There are currently no services')");
        }

        if (ZipCodeValidator.isValid(zipcode)) {
            ajaxRequestTarget.add(tableHolder);
            if (searchProduct != null && !searchProduct.equals("")) {
                ajaxRequestTarget.add(productTableHolder);
                if (lstProduct.getList().size() == 0) {
                    ajaxRequestTarget
                            .appendJavaScript("$().toastmessage('showErrorToast','Sorry! This product is not avialable in this zip code or zone.')");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want when this method is called till the times it fetch the result data , it should show a preloader or spinner . Can anybody suggest how to do that .??

Comment: maybe not a duplicate but very closely related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337198/wicket-calling-a-lengthy-operation-and-updating-through-ajax/15338934

Comment: @Nicktar you are absolutely correct it is related to that.I found that link lateron after I post the question , I found my answer anyways , thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call long execution method by clicking button check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582084/is-there-an-activity-indicator-in-wicket) answer.
You can also use AjaxLazyLoadPanel, check [this demo](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/lazy-loading) (it's [Java part](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage?7&SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.ajax.builtin.LazyLoadingPage&source=LazyLoadingPage.java) and [html part](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage?6&SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.ajax.builtin.LazyLoadingPage&source=LazyLoadingPage.html))

Comment: thanks for your reply , I know that part and link but I think I can't used that in a ajax call ,its rather better to change the button type that will automatically show the spinner .

Answer (score 0):

Either use an AjaxLazyLoadPanel or an IndicatingAjaxLink/-Button. Both will work fine in either normal or Ajax calls.

To use an AjaxLazyLoadPanel: create a subclass of AjaxLazyLoadPanel which loads the panel you want to display and add it to the AjaxRequest.

IndicatingAjaxLinks just display a spinner while the request is being processed and can be used straightforward in your current application. Use this instead of the button/link you use for formsubmits now.